# Whether It is Boxing Or Unboxing?

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

> int i = 5;
>
> string str = i.ToString();
>
> String str1=(String) i.ToString();

As `Int` 's are value Type and `String` 's are reference Type

so Whether It is Boxing Or Unboxing ???

EDIT:
Now For Second Statement Whether It is Boxing Or Unboxing ???

Comment: for unboxing you have to explicitly mention the data type like its unboxing version is: string str = (string)i;

Comment: I don't think this is boxing or unboxing.

Comment: @UsmanWaheed is it unboxing?

Comment: In this case, the answer is actually neither. Some methods on `int` require boxing, but because `ToString()` is virtual on `object` and overridden by `int`, no box is necessary here.

Comment: @Saurabh It is neither - see my answer and dlev's comment :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not an example of unboxing or boxing, but instead a method invocation of `Int32.ToString()` and assigning the return value to a `string`. The `i.ToString()` call doesn't assign an `int` to an object, but passes it to a method which returns a `string`. The second line with the `(string)` cast is superfluous and the C# compiler doesn't even emit it into IL.

For example, if you had this in a main method:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
// Method begins at RVA 0x2050
// Code size 19 (0x13)
.maxstack 1
.entrypoint
.locals init (
    [0] int32 i
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.5
IL_0001: stloc.0
IL_0002: ldloca.s i
IL_0004: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
IL_0009: pop
IL_000a: ldloca.s i
IL_000c: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString() // cast isn't here
IL_0011: pop
IL_0012: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

If you were boxing an integer:

```
int i = 1; 
object iBox = i;
```

emits:

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 i,
    [1] object o
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldloc.0
IL_0004: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0009: stloc.1
IL_000a: ret
```

Notice the `box` op code. If you aren't sure if something is boxing or unboxing, you can view the IL and see if this op code is there.

If you were unboxing an integer:

```
int j = (int) iBox;
```

The process is similar for other value types, like `bool` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. 
In this case it is neither boxing nor unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap.

Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. 
Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit.

The concept of boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

In the following example, the integer variable i is boxed and assigned to object o.

**C#**

```
int i = 123;
// The following line boxes i. 
object o = i;
```

The object o can then be unboxed and assigned to integer variable i:

**C#**

```
o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing
```

Comment: The answer is clear, however you're not answering the actual question whether his code is an example of boxing or unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

boxing is happened when you assign your data to object data type. since you are not doing this, there it is not boxing or unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

boxing is used to convert value type(except string) to object type 
use ToString() method for boxing
unboxing is used to convert object type to reference type(string)
use  anydatatype(except string).parse() method